# How to make ANTLR4 grammar support escaping characters?

Tags: java, parsing, antlr, antlr4

I have the following ANTLR4 grammar to interpret regular expressions.

```
// Regular Expression Grammar.
grammar RegExpr;

program  : expr EOF # Root
        ;
expr     : TERM # TermNode
        | expr '?' # OptionalNode
        | '(' expr ')' # OrdinaryNode
        | expr expr # ConcatNode
        | expr '|' expr # OrNode
        ;
ESC      : '\\' . ;
TERM     : ([a-zA-Z0-9,.*^+\-&'":><#![\]] | ESC)+ ;
WS       : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ; // skip spaces, tabs, newlines
```

However, when I try to parse string literal '\\(' in Java, I got

> line 1:0 no viable alternative at input '\('

I want to treat any character with '\\' prefix as terminals.  For example, '\\(', '\\)', '\\\\', '\\X' are treated as terminals.

In the end, I want to parse '\(a.(b|c)\)' as

> '\(a.' (b|c) '\)'

which represents '\(a.b\)' and '\(a.c\)'.  Then I can remove all '\'s to get '(a.b)' and '(a.c)'.

Can anyone please point out why does the above grammar gives errors on '\\(' and '\(a.(b|c)\)'?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The original question already has an answer (using `fragment`) however I think there is still a lack of understanding. So here's an explanation:

In ANTLR lexer rules are being processed in the order they are specified in the grammar. So ANTLR will start with the first rule and tried if it can match the current input character-sequence. If it can a token will be created and the process starts all over again. If it can't the next lexer rule is consulted.

In your example `ESC` is specified before `TERM`. Therefore ANTLR will try to match the input as `ESC` before it will try to match it as `TERM`. Thus the input `\.` will always be matched as a single `ESC` token and only the following characters (that no longer match `ESC`) will be matched with `TERM`.

By defining `ESC` to be a fragment you are telling ANTLR that `ESC`isn't a lexer rule by itself. Therefore it won't be asked to match the character inputStream. Fragments are just reusable parts that can be used to assemble actual lexer rules and therefore the first declared (and consulted) lexer rule in your grammar becomes `TERM`.
In fact the only advantage of using fragments is if you have multiple lexer rules that at some point all contain the same sequence (e.g. `'\\' .`). In order to not have to write that sequence every time you can pre-define that sequence as a fragment. So basically you can think of fragments as a sort of variable holding the actual sequence that can be inserted into lexer rules.

Long story short: The problem was solved because fragments will not create tokens while normal lexer rules will.

Comment: Not entirely true - if the input is `\abc`, lexer will match it as `TERM` rather than match the leading `\a` as `ESC`. Order is a secondary factor only used when multiple rules can match same input subsequence (i.e. same length).

Comment: The order is the first factor as far as the lexer is concerned. About your example: Are you referring to the version where `ESC` is defined as a fragment? If not then in `\abc` `\a` will indeed be matched as `ESC`

Comment: If that was true, you wouldn't be able to define keywords in ANTLR. E.g. if you wanted to define keyword `begin`, how would it handle matching `beginner` as an identifier? If keyword is defined below identifier, it would never be matched, and if it's above identifier, it would according to you match `begin` prefix as keyword and then be left with `ner`.

Comment: Yeah that is the case afaik. If you want to define keywords you need to embed an action in the ID rule chaning the created token type or you need to include a word separator in your keyword definition...

Answer (score 0):

OK.  I somehow can fix the grammar with

```
fragment ESC      : '\\' . ;
```

Not sure what exactly happens here.

Answer (score 0):

Since `ESC` wasn't a fragment in your original grammar, and was above `TERM` in the grammar file, it took priority over `TERM` whenever lexer could just match `\.` and nothing longer.

Comment: Because `program` rule cannot match `ESC` token that is on input.